# WebDeploy publish not uploading PDB files (MVC precompiled webapp, VS2013)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msdeploy, webdeploy, pdb-files

When publishing a web application using IIS WebDeploy via the Publish command within Visual Studio (2014 in this case), all the files except the primary assemblys PDB file is uploaded.

The web.config has `debug=false` set. The relevant build configuration has pdb-only set, and the publish profile is set to emit debug information.

**Why are the pdb files not being uploaded?**

[image]
[image]

Rather confusingly, the pdb files for the compiled MVC views are included, just not the the pdbs for any actual assemblies used.

> Adding file (domain\bin\App_Web_x13lezpq.pdb). // A MVC Compiled View
>   Updating file (domain\bin\MyWebApplication.dll). // The main DLL has
>   no PDB uploaded, although one is generated in the bin folder anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved, there is a third place to set the pdb settings - ensure the checkbox for 'Exclude generated debug symbols' is not checked.

[image]